# Jquery script isn't working in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to add a script from Stackoverflow that took ages to come by,
but it seems like the file is going against me, though it's working perfectly
fine in JSfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hqtsmayh/

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div id="mysliders">
            <label for="slider-1">Slider:</label>
            <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" min="0" max="100" value="50" />
            <label for="slider-2">Slider:</label>
            <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" min="0" max="100" value="40" />
            <label for="slider-3">Slider:</label>
            <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-3" id="slider-3" min="0" max="100" value="30" />
            <label for="slider-4">Slider:</label>
            <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-4" id="slider-4" min="0" max="100" value="65" />
            <label for="slider-5">Slider:</label>
            <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-5" id="slider-5" min="0" max="100" value="11" />
            <label for="slider-6">Slider:</label>
            <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-6" id="slider-6" min="0" max="100" value="90" />
        </div>
        <hr />
        <p>Total: <strong id="total"></strong></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Footer</h1> 
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
            $(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
                $(".add").on("change", function () {
                    addAll();
                });

                addAll();
            });

            function addAll() {
                var sum = 0
                $('.add').each(function (){        
                    sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);        
                });
                $('#total').html(sum);
            }
    });
</script>
```

All I have in the header is a Jquery attachment:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And this is of course for mobile, using jQuery mobile?

Comment: Your jsfiddle options are not wrapping the code in a load method, whereas in your example code here it's inside `$(window).load`.  May or may not affect anything, but it's potentially a big difference.

Comment: `sum += isNaN(this.value)`. If `this.value` is not a number, that statement will be `sum += true`, which is equivalent to `sum += 1`. Is that intended?

Comment: Include jquery mobile, and as a recommendation, use the last jquery stable version. jquery 1.10.2 version is years and years old!!!

Comment: When you say "not working", what specifically isn't working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: You can see here without including jquery mobile that doesn't work, equal to your case: http://jsfiddle.net/hqtsmayh/2/

Comment: You also need to make sure the versions of `jQuery` and `jQuery Mobile` you have are actually compatible.

Comment: My version with just the .load works just fine on my iPhone. I would expect it to work elsewhere too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just this? tested in mobile Safari

Also beware of jsFiddle's default onload

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".add").on("change", function() {
      addAll();
    });
    addAll();
  });

  function addAll() {
    var sum = 0
    $('.add').each(function() {
      sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
    });
    $('#total').html(sum);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>My page</h1> 
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div id="mysliders">
      <label for="slider-1">Slider:</label>
      <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" min="0" max="100" value="50" />
      <label for="slider-2">Slider:</label>
      <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" min="0" max="100" value="40" />
      <label for="slider-3">Slider:</label>
      <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-3" id="slider-3" min="0" max="100" value="30" />
      <label for="slider-4">Slider:</label>
      <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-4" id="slider-4" min="0" max="100" value="65" />
      <label for="slider-5">Slider:</label>
      <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-5" id="slider-5" min="0" max="100" value="11" />
      <label for="slider-6">Slider:</label>
      <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-6" id="slider-6" min="0" max="100" value="90" />
    </div>
    <hr />
    <p>Total: <strong id="total"></strong>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Footer</h1> 
  </div>
</div>
```